# Filter array of objects by another array of objects with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, filter

The below is my code. The "id" will have same value. I want to filter data by multiple keys. Filter is not happening properly.

```
let myArray = [
    {
        "id": "#prodstck",
        "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "#prodstck",
        "date": "2018-04-24T16:43:42Z"
    },
];

let filterArray = [
    {
        "id": "#prodstck",
        "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
    }
];

 const filterFeed = myArray.filter(obj=> filterArray.some((f: any) =>
            f.id !== obj.id && f.date !== obj.date
        ));
```

Thank you

Comment: *"Filter is not happening properly."* What is it supposed to do? What is it doing instead?

Comment: It should filter and show:
    [{
            "id": "#prodstck",
            "date": "2018-04-24T16:43:42Z"
    }];

But it's showing empty, since id is same.

Comment: To improve/clarify the question, please use the "edit" link.

Comment: Re your [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52145478/157247): `find` isn't the right tool, `some` (the function you used) is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will return the item with 16:43:21 timestamp.

```js
let myArray = [
    {
        "id": "#prodstck",
        "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "#prodstck",
        "date": "2018-04-24T16:43:42Z"
    },
];

let filterArray = [
    {
        "id": "#prodstck",
        "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
    }
];


const result = myArray.filter(item => {
 return filterArray.some(filterItem => item.id === filterItem.id && item.date === filterItem.date)  
})

console.log(result);
```

Edit: Changed .find to .some like the OP originally had.

Comment: The OP's `some`, rather than `find`, is the correct function in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, it's just your `some` condition is incorrect. It should be:

```
f.id === obj.id && f.date === obj.date
```

That is, you want `some` to return `true` (so that `filter` keeps the entry) when both the `id` and the `date` match one of the entries in your second array.

Live Example:

```js
let myArray = [{
    "id": "#prodstck",
    "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "#prodstck",
    "date": "2018-04-24T16:43:42Z"
  },
];

let filterArray = [{
  "id": "#prodstck",
  "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
}];

const filterFeed = myArray.filter(obj => filterArray.some((f/*: any*/) =>
  f.id === obj.id && f.date === obj.date
));

console.log(filterFeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from both the callback function & the condition will check for eqality

```js
let myArray = [{
    "id": "#prodstck",
    "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "#prodstck",
    "date": "2018-04-24T16:43:42Z"
  },
];

let filterArray = [{
  "id": "#prodstck",
  "date": "2018-07-24T16:43:21Z"
}];

const filterFeed = myArray.filter(function(obj) {
  return filterArray.some(function(f) {
    return f.id === obj.id && f.date === obj.date
  })
});

console.log(filterFeed)
```